# How to display value of two Spinner(present in one activity) in a TextView: Android

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, spinner

I am unable to display the value of selected spinner in the TextView.
None of the spinner value is being displayed.
Is there any way to display values of both the spinners?

here is the code

```
public class Calculator extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    Spinner temp1,temp2;
    TextView t1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);

        t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);

        temp1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.temp);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>   adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.temperature,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
           adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    temp1.setAdapter(adapter);

       temp2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.temp2);
       ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.temperature,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
      adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    temp2.setAdapter(adapter2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Spinner temp1=(Spinner)parent;
        Spinner temp2=(Spinner)parent;
        if (temp1.getId()==R.id.temp) {
            String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            t1.setText(item);
        }
        if (temp2.getId()==R.id.temp2) {
            String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            t1.setText(item);
        }

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not added listener to your spinners.

Use:

```
temp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
temp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: where should i add the listener? under public void onItemSelected ?

Comment: inside onCreate() method itself. Add it in the last time.